# Writing UI table data to a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, selenium

New to C# and am trying to take data from a data table on a website and save it into a csv file. So far I've managed to get the data into the csv file but each record appends to a new cell in column A (as viewed in Excel). i.e...

```
  A           B           C
1 A_record1
2 A_record2
3 A_record3
4 B_record1
5 B_record2
6 B_record3
```

Whereas I would like the data to be in the csv file in the format...

```
  A           B           C
1 A_record1   A_record2   A_record3
2 B_record1   B_record2   B_record3
```

The code I have which populates the csv in the first example is...

```
//divided xpath In three parts to pass Row_count and Col_count values.
String firstPart = "//div[@id='lwDataGrid']/table/tbody/tr[";
String secondPart = "]/td[";
String thirdPart = "]";

//Row and Column counts
int rowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='lwDataGrid']/table/tbody/tr[*]")).Count - 3;
int colCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='lwDataGrid']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")).Count;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rowCount + ": This is the number of rows in the table");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(colCount + ": This is the number of columns in the table");

string path = @"C:\...\my.csv";

for (int j = 2; j <= colCount; j++)
{
    //Used for loop for number of columns.
    for (int i = 4; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        //Prepared final xpath of specific cell as per values of i and j.
        String finalXpath = firstPart + i + secondPart + j + thirdPart;
        //Will retrieve value from located cell and print It.
        String tableData = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(finalXpath)).Text; 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(tableData);
        }
    }
}
```

The final goal is to compare this csv with another "expected outcome" csv to check that the data in the UI table is as expected. If there's a more efficient way than comparing two files i.e. using an array to compare to the outcome csv I'm open to suggestions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code from -

```
for (int j = 2; j <= colCount; j++)
{
    //Used for loop for number of columns.
    for (int i = 4; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        //Prepared final xpath of specific cell as per values of i and j.
        String finalXpath = firstPart + i + secondPart + j + thirdPart;
        //Will retrieve value from located cell and print It.
        String tableData = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(finalXpath)).Text; 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(tableData);
        }
    }
}
```

to below might solve the issue

```
    for (int j = 2; j <= colCount; j++)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                string line = string.Empty;
                //Used for loop for number of columns.
                for (int i = 4; i <= rowCount; i++)
                {
                    //Prepared final xpath of specific cell as per values of i and j.
                    String finalXpath = firstPart + i + secondPart + j + thirdPart;
                    //Will retrieve value from located cell and print It.
                    String tableData = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(finalXpath)).Text;
                    line = line + string.Format("{0},",tableData);
                }
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! That gets's me a little further, although I now need to handle different column values differently as column 3 data has a number with commas (i.e. 51,100.00) which splits over 2 columns.

Comment: Actually, just tried wrapping tabledata in quotes and it works i.e. line = line + string.Format("{0},", "\"" + tableData + "\"");

Comment: Instead of comma separated file you may use a pipe symbol or any symbol that is not used as part of the data. Then while importing the file you can specify that symbol as delimiter.

Comment: One last point is that the first row is always empty. I can't see which part of the code is causing this?